# Query String discrepancy in Adobe Contribute/Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver, dreamweaver-templates, adobe-contribute

/*****Update ******/
This seems to be a query string problem, as I didn't realize that a PHP error was being thrown in Contribute 3. So my question now is, why does this line work in Contribute 4, but not in 3: **#include virtual="includes/scripts/name.php?eid=@@(eid)@@"**

/****************/

Hello everyone, I have a couple of different versions of Contribute in my organization. We built a template that works for the CS4 version, but has a peculiar error in the CS3 version, and I was wondering if a Contribute expert might provide some guidance.

We built the template in Dreamweaver, with the standard TemplateParam statements at the top. All of them are just editable regions except for one, the ID field:
    TemplateParam name="eid" type="text" content="your eid"

Values based on that ID are fetched and formatted with a PHP script in the template body:
    #include virtual="includes/scripts/name.php?eid=@@(eid)@@"

The problem is that if we attempt to edit any template properties in CS3, such as turning them on or off, it will disable our PHP script completely (all fields come back empty), and we have to abandon the changes. Not so in Contribute 4, which works as expected.

This is a pretty specific inquiry, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be to simply replace the double quotes in the includes path with single quotes. Works correctly for both versions now.